# How can I find a proper transformation for this multiple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to integrate $\iint x^2 y^2 dA$ over the region constrained by $xy=1$, $xy=2$, $y=x$, $y=4x$ and I have to do so by using a tranformation to change variables. But I Tried like 3 or 4 options and neither of them got me an easier integral. I've tried things like $x=\frac  u v$ , $y=v$, and $x=\sqrt u$, $y=\sqrt v$ but I mostly get stuck with a jacobian that is $\frac 1 u$ or $\frac 1 v$ and that leaves me with a very complex function to integrate over an area with square roots, involving $ln$ and such.

How can I find a proper transformation for this one? I'm failing to see what would be more convenient.

Comment: If you try $u = xy$ and $v = \dfrac{y}{x}$, then your bounds will be integers.

Comment: Why, thank you! Although those partial derivatives were hell to solve! Unless I did something wrong, I ended up with $x=\frac {\sqrt u}{\sqrt v}$ and $y=v\frac {\sqrt u}{\sqrt v}$ and the jacobian (after much simplification) is $\frac 1 v + \frac {1}{2v}$